Prefill Docusign Fields using the Docusign API
I've created a template via the Docusign dashboard. This template has a prefill field with Data Label "project_name". I then create an envelope via the API (python SDK) and get the envelope ID. The next step I take is to populate the prefilled fields using "create_document_tabs" method.
Note: this isn't a recipient field, and therefor I am not pushing the "tabs" into template_role, rather using "create_document_tabs". The other questions I've seen here address fields for users.
Here is my code to create template roles, the envelope, and tabs:
def create_ds_envelope(args):
    # create envelope definition with template_id
    envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition(
        status='created', template_id=args["template_id"], email_subject=args['email_subject']
    )

    template_roles = []

    for role in args['template_roles']:
        template_roles.append(
            docusign.TemplateRole(
                email=role['role_email'], name=role['signer_name'],
                role_name=role['role_name'], routing_order=role['routing_order']
            )
        )

    envelope_definition.template_roles = template_roles

    api_client = create_api_client(base_path=args["base_uri"], access_token=args["access_token"])

    envelope_api = docusign.EnvelopesApi(api_client=api_client)

    # create envelope
    envelope_id = envelope_api.create_envelope(
        account_id=args['account_id'], envelope_definition=envelope_definition
    ).envelope_id

    # create document tabs
    # args['template_fields'] holds tab_label and value
    envelope_api.create_document_tabs(
        account_id=args['account_id'], document_id='1', envelope_id=envelope_id,
        tabs=docusign.Tabs(
            prefill_tabs=docusign.PrefillTabs(
                text_tabs=[
                    docusign.Text(
                        tab_label=efg['label'], value=efg['value'], document_id='1'
                    ) for efg in args['template_fields']
                ]
            )
        )
    )

    return envelope_id, api_client

I've followed the following:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields#python

pre-fill fields are best used when a human will send the envelope--the sender adds the field data as part of the sending process.
When an API app sends the envelope, I recommend that you use a regular tab (field). Set it to locked so it can't be changed by the recipient.
This way:

You have the choice of more tab types
You can use the composite templates pattern for creating the envelope


The issue with your code is that you're not positioning the tab anywhere. You didn't even provide a page number like the blog post you're linking  to shows you.
If you provide just a page_number it should already show on that page at the very top/left corner (0/0 coordinates) but you can also put x_position and y_position to place it in a specific spot on the page.
The Python code should be fixed to something like this:
  envelope_api.create_document_tabs(
        account_id=args['account_id'], document_id='1', envelope_id=envelope_id,
        tabs=docusign.Tabs(
            prefill_tabs=docusign.PrefillTabs(
                text_tabs=[
                    docusign.Text(
                        tab_label=efg['label'], value=efg['value'], document_id='1', page_number='1', x_position='100', y_position='100'
                    ) for efg in args['template_fields']
                ]
            )
        )
    )


Inbar's solution is correct for when creating a new field via the API. However, it was not working for the case where a template was created via the webapp, and fields were being populated via the API. Here are the steps to setting values to fields in a template:

Create the envelope definition

Create api_client and envelope

Get document tabs
document_tabs = envelope_api.get_document_tabs(
account_id=args['account_id'], document_id='1', envelope_id=envelope_id)


Loop through the tabs in prefill.text_tabs and update values accordingly
for text_tab in document_tabs.prefill_tabs.text_tabs:
ds_template_field = next(
    (field for field in args['template_fields'] if field['label'] == text_tab.tab_label), None
)

if ds_template_field:
    text_tab.value = ds_template_field['value']


Finally, update the document tabs by sending bad the updated Tab object
envelope_api.update_document_tabs(
account_id=args['account_id'], document_id='1', envelope_id=envelope_id, tabs=document_tabs)




Your solution is a good one, but it is best (and required by the API Usage guidelines) to use a minimum number of API calls whenever reasonable to do so. If you use standard (locked) tabs attached to the first signer recipient, then you can use the composite templates pattern to set them when you create/send the envelope. This also works when the envelope is initially defined via a template (recommended).
